# ADO.NET MVC Query foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have two models connected with a foreign key, User and Farm.

I want to be able to select a user with a query and type:

```
@Model.Farm.FarmId
```

In my view. This wont work because the farm prop is null.

[image: Null]

**These are my two models:**

**Model 1:**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }  

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }

    public int FarmId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FarmId")]
    public virtual Farm Farm { get; set; }
}
```

**Model 2:**

```
public class Farm
{
    public Farm()
    {
            User = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int FarmId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

**GET USER Query:**

```
public User GetUser(string userName)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = @UserName";

    User user = null;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    UserId = (int)rdr["UserId"],
                    UserName = (string)rdr["UserName"],
                    Password = (string)rdr["Password"],
                    PasswordSalt = (string)rdr["PasswordSalt"],
                    Money = (int)rdr["Money"],
                    FarmId = (int)rdr["FarmId"],

                    Farm ??????
                };
            }

            if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    return user;
}
```

My guess is I have to do some kind of join, right? I'm still a query-newbie so have patience with me please:)

I dont want to use linq!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use Entity Framework or something similar... without actually using it?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I have created my database with codefirst using Entity Framework. Now im trying to access the data from this database using queries, not linq.

Comment: Use Linq[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574049/ado-net-mvc-query-foreign-key?noredirect=1#comment41765855_26574049)

Comment: Lol i dont want to use linq. Im trying to learn queries here!;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a join to your SQL query as below

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users JOIN Farm ON Farm.FarmId = Users.FarmId WHERE UserName = @UserName";
```

then create an instance of `Farm` and assign it to `user.Farm` inside the `while (rdr.Read())` block

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    user = new User
    {
        UserId = (int)rdr["UserId"],
        UserName = (string)rdr["UserName"],
        Password = (string)rdr["Password"],
        PasswordSalt = (string)rdr["PasswordSalt"],
        Money = (int)rdr["Money"],
        FarmId = (int)rdr["FarmId"]
    };

    Farm farm = new Farm();
    farm.FarmId = (int)rdr["FarmId"];
    farm.Created = (DateTime)rdr["Created"];
    farm.Age = (int)rdr["Age"];

    user.Farm = farm;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for :) Thhhaanks

Comment: if i wanted to pass the farm field to the table on the view,could it work with something like this? only i would add a view model maybe? or two models in a view?

Comment: @Alexander yes it could work with something like this. You would add a view model that contains all of the properties you need in the view.

Comment: sorry,just one little quick question..would it also work if I had a calculate column? somethink like SELECT (column1-column2) AS Counter FROM...

Comment: @Alexander yes it would work. I'd create a `Counter` property in the view model and map the calculate column to `Counter`, i.e something like `Counter = (int)rdr["Counter"]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use plain `SqlConnection`, ditch Entity Framework altogether. It's not going to help you. The metadata you've added to your objects will go unused.

Even with Entity Framework you can theoretically use [`DbSet.SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696332(v=vs.113).aspx) or a similar method to run custom SQL queries and get back live objects. I don't think there's a documented way to eager load dependencies via a JOIN though. You'll end up with lazy loading support only, i.e. SELECT queries in a loop when you enumerate things.

If you absolutely must use your convoluted manual way instead of a simple Linq one-liner, then what you want is a simple [`INNER JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx) (or `LEFT JOIN` if the Farm is optional). That way you will get all the fields from the Farm table on each row as well. You can then manually instantiate your Farm object for each User the same way you're doing with the rest of the fields.

ProTips:

1. Use `using()` with the reader to ensure it gets closed properly instead of your if
2. An empty `catch { }` is not going to help you debug things.
3. Why use a `while` loop if you're only expecting one result?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use EntityFramework, you must build Farm object yourself.

Try join user and farm to get farm object that connected to user:

```
select * from users u
join farms f on u.farmid = f.farmid
where username == @username
```

And then build Farm object.

Comment: Hey! I've tried this before and got the join query to work, but I don't know what to do next. You think you could give me some more code and show me what you mean? Thanks!